# Getting WhatsApp to work on my phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, whatsapp.app

I use WhatsApp and currently it won't let me log on and use it.

Things I've tried so far:

- deleting and reinstalling the app.
- turning my phone off and back on again.
- putting it in to and out of airplane mode.

None of these steps have worked. I've read resetting network settings might help but I'm unsure what that would do to my phone overall.

Is there some way to diagnose what's going on with WhatsApp and fix it?

Comment: Please include the version of iOS your phone is running as their appear to be problems with newer versions of WhatsApp depending on what version of iOS you are running. And do read our [help area](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask good questions here on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I suppose it is asking the obvious, but is there a chance that there is problem with the app itself or your login credentials? Would you be willing to post some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you haven't updated the iOS till now, cause the last update of Whatsapp made it unusable on iOS 5 and 4. This has now been fixed with the new update. Please update the App or your iOS for the same.

Answer (score -2):

Try updating your iPhone then installing the watsapp again..